# To accelerate FunctionCompile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I have a function `value` like this:

```
groups = N[{{40, 23, 213, 79, 18, 152, 105, 191, 119, 243}, {86, 3, 152, 89, 
     52, 36, 132, 196, 159, 108, 200}, {253, 223, 167, 197, 147, 112, 
     225, 98, 159, 163, 245, 240, 267}, {89, 164, 156, 124, 15, 253, 
     41, 171, 209, 132}}];

PopulationVariance1[list_] := Mean[(list - Mean[list])^2]

value[groups_] := Module[{mean, SSA, SSE}, mean = Mean[Flatten[groups]];
  SSA = Total[Table[Length[group]*(Mean[group] - mean)^2, {group, groups}]];
  SSE = Total[Table[Length[group]*PopulationVariance1[group], {group, groups}]];
  (SSA/(Length[groups] - 1))/(SSE/(Length[Flatten[groups]] - Length[groups]))]

value[groups]
```

> 3.6118

This is my current compilation try:

```
dec = FunctionDeclaration[PopulationVariance, 
   Typed[{"PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]} -> "Real64"]@
    Function[list, Mean[(list - Mean[list])^2]]];

cfvalue = FunctionCompile[dec, 
  Function[Typed[groups, "ListVector"::["ListVector"::["Real64"]]], 
   Module[{mean, SSA, SSE}, 
    mean = Mean[
      Cast[Catenate[groups], "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]];
    SSA = Total[Cast[
       Length[#]*(Mean[Cast[#, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]] - 
             mean)^2 & /@ groups, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]];
    SSE = Total[Cast[
       Length[#]*PopulationVariance[
           Cast[#, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]] & /@ groups, 
       "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]];
    (SSA/(Length[groups] - 1))/(SSE/(Length[Catenate[groups]] - 
         Length[groups]))]]]

cfvalue[groups]
```

> 3.6118

It works indeed. However, I found that **the compiler function was even slower than the uncompiled one**.

```
lis = DeleteCases[Table[ResourceFunction["RandomSplit"][RandomReal[255, 1000], 10], 
    100000], {}, {2}];
Timing[value /@ lis;](*{15.2813, Null}*)
Timing[cfvalue /@ lis;](*{23., Null}*)
```

Could you please help me improve the speed of the `cfvalue`?

---

```
$Version
```

> 13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)

Comment: Dear @yode. I get syntax error for your `Typed[{"PackedArray"::["Real64",1]}->"Real64"]` in Version 12.3. Concerning your question, I see that your `value` code is nice and simple. I wonder if in 202x, with just-in-time compilation and all that jazz, Mathematica does not automatically optimize code such as yours, and nothing is gained by explicitly compiling yourself? I am sure you know much more about this than I do.

Comment: @user293787 The new syntax of `TypeSpecifier` is added in _v13.1_.

Comment: @user293787 Hi, I'm in version 13.1,If you are in 12.3, you should use `Typed[{TypeSpecifier["PackedArray"]["Real64", 1]} -> "Real64"]`

Comment: On my computer, the whole operation with `value` on the `lis` took `19` seconds (`cfvalue` was 32 seconds), I was curious to see how a low-level version would perform, so I tried it on Rust and it took `5.6` seconds which if we ignore the time it takes to convert the input to `NumericArray`, it was `0.4` second! Clearly, there is much room for improvement.

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks, this confirms that OP has a legit expectation that the compiled code should be faster. I would find it useful if you posted details about this as an answer, even if it is more supporting material rather than an actual answer. But not sure if Mathematica SE allows such answers.

Comment: @user293787 I was going to but since the question is around `FunctionCompile`, I decided to leave it as a comment. If OP agrees, I would share the workflow. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @BenIzd I think that will be a valuable sharing

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### The Code

Here's some equivalent code that performs a better:

```
cfValue = 
 FunctionCompile[
  Function[Typed[groups, "ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]],
   Module[{
     PopulationVariance = 
      Function[{Typed[g, "PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]]},
       Mean[(g - Mean[g])^2]
       ], mean, total, SSA, SSE, len},
    
    total = 
     Fold[Plus[#1, #2] &, 
      Map[Typed[Total, {"PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]} -> "Real64"], 
       groups]];
    len = 
     Fold[Plus[#1, #2] &, 
      Map[Typed[
        Length, {"PackedArray"::["Real64", 1]} -> "Integer64"], 
       groups]];
    
    mean = total/ len;
    
    SSA = 
     Fold[Plus[#1, #2] &, Length[#]*(Mean[#] - mean)^2 & /@ groups];
    SSE = 
     Fold[Plus[#1, #2] &, 
      Map[Length[#]*PopulationVariance[#] &, groups]];
    (SSA/(Length[groups] - 1))/(SSE/(len - Length[groups])) 
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

### Timing

On my machine with Mathematica 13.1:

```
In[111]:= AbsoluteTiming[cfValue[#] & /@ lis;]

Out[111]= {3.04551, Null}

In[112]:= AbsoluteTiming[value[#] & /@ lis;]

Out[112]= {10.4156, Null}
```

### Why

The casting in code from the question was cloning the data each time which is very expensive.

This function avoids casting by instead using a Fold with Plus to total the ListVectors.

Comment: Hi Richards, what is `CompileToCodeFunction` in your code? Searching that in M13.1's documentation center doesn't hit anything.

Comment: Ah its the same as FunctionCompile, I will edit the code to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! (+1) A bit off-topic: does casting in the new compiler always cause data copy (even the "BitCast" version)?

Comment: It depends upon the types and the scenario. A cast of an atomic type to another atomic type (eg, Integer32 to Integer64) necessarily will. A cast from PackedArray[Int32] to NumericArray[Int32] it is possible the data would not be cloned as they are both immutable arrays. However, as PackedArray and ListVector are fundamentally different data types (one an array, one a linked list or something) there is necessarily a clone of the data. This is the same as if you cast a list to an array in any language.

Comment: BitCast is the same as Cast for the most part

Comment: `Fold[Plus[#1, #2] &, {a, b, c, d}]` equal to `Fold[Plus, {a, b, c, d}]` :)

Comment: A little strange. Your function behave better [in my computer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9OpQ.png)

Comment: I'm confused, why your `FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[groups,"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64",1]]],Fold[Typed[Plus,{"Real64","Real64"}->"Real64"],Map[Total,groups]]]]` works but `FunctionCompile[Function[Typed[groups,"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64",1]]],Typed[Total,{"ListVector"::["Real64"]}->"Real64"][Map[Total,groups]]]]` fail?

Comment: Hi Yode, 
Yes I added the #1 and & when I was struggling with the type system but its unnecessary, whoops. 
The Total does not work because Total has not been implemented for `ListVector`s. Hopefully it will be added for a future update.

Comment: @A.Richards Thank you for that very useful information! @yode You can use `$CompilerEnvironment["TypeEnvironment"]["getPolymorphicList", f ]` to check compilable type of function `f`. It shows `Total` is only defined for container types belong to `DenseArrays`, OTOH `Fold` is defined for all types belong to `RangeIterable`. We can check `ListVector` is not a kind of `DenseArrays` but is a kind of `RangeIterable`. So `Fold` is compilable here but `Total` is not.

Comment: @yode BTW to check if one type is a "kind" of certain abstract type, you can do this: ``env=$CompilerEnvironment@"TypeEnvironment";env["implementsQ","resolve"~env~"ListVector","resolve"~env~TypeFramework`AbstractType@"RangeIterable"]`` .

Comment: @Silvia It's a MAGIC dig...

Answer (score 9):

I decide to use Rust to show how much improvement we can achieve while also benefiting from the Rust memory management system which prevents us to leak memory (to some extent).

Recently Wolfram started a project called [`wolfram-library-link-rs`](https://github.com/WolframResearch/wolfram-library-link-rs) which is a Rust crate (aka library/module/etc) which allows users to code in Rust and export their functions without doing much for the interface with Mathematica.

To follow this workflow you need to install [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) and have an internet connection when you build the project (I think only the first time is required).

Create a Rust project, replace `Cargo.toml` content with the following:

```
[package]
name = "population_variance"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]

[dependencies]
wolfram-library-link = "0.2.5"
```

and replace `src/lib.rs` content with this:

```rust
use wolfram_library_link::{export, NumericArray};

type Precision = f64;
type ArrayType = Precision;

fn population_variance(array: &[ArrayType]) -> Precision {
    let mean = array.iter().sum::<ArrayType>() as f64 / array.len() as Precision;
    array.iter().map(|&x| (x as Precision - mean).powf(2.0)).sum::<Precision>() as Precision / array.len() as Precision
}

fn value(groups: Vec<&[ArrayType]>) -> Precision {
    let total: ArrayType = groups.iter().map(|group| group.iter().sum::<ArrayType>()).sum::<ArrayType>();
    let flatten_length: usize = groups.iter().map(|group| group.len()).sum();
    let mean = total as Precision / flatten_length as Precision;
    let groups_len = groups.len();

    let ssa = groups.iter().map(|group| group.len() as Precision * ((group.iter().sum::<ArrayType>() as Precision) / (group.len() as Precision) - mean).powf(2.0)).sum::<Precision>();
    let sse = groups.iter().map(|group| group.len() as Precision * population_variance(group)).sum::<Precision>();
    (ssa / (groups_len - 1) as Precision) / (sse / (flatten_length - groups_len) as Precision)
}

#[export]
fn mathematica_interface(data: &NumericArray<ArrayType>, lengths: &NumericArray<i64>) -> Precision {
    let data_slice = data.as_slice();
    let mut vectors: Vec<&[ArrayType]> = Vec::with_capacity(lengths.flattened_length());
    let mut current_index: usize = 0;
    for &length in lengths.as_slice() {
        let length = length as usize;

        vectors.push(&data_slice[current_index..(current_index + length)]);
        current_index += length;
    }

    value(vectors)
}
```

When you build the project (with `build --release`), you will get a `population_variance.dll` in the `target/release` directory.

In Mathematica use the following code to use the library (change the path to your address):

```
compiledValue = 
 LibraryFunctionLoad["C:\\population_variance.dll", 
  "mathematica_interface", {{LibraryDataType[NumericArray, "Real64"], 
    "Constant"}, {LibraryDataType[NumericArray, "Integer64"], 
    "Constant"}}, Real];

ClearAll[RustValue];

RustValue[data_] := Block[{lengths = Length /@ data},
  compiledValue[NumericArray[Flatten@data, "Real64"], 
   NumericArray[lengths, "Integer64"]]
  ]
```

Now it will work as a normal function:

```
Block[{data = N@{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7, 9}}},
 {value[data], cfvalue[data], RustValue[data]}
 ]

(* Out: {11.8125, 11.8125, 11.8125} *)
```

Testing larger dataset:

```
Block[{data = N@lis},
 {value /@ data // Total // AbsoluteTiming, 
  cfvalue /@ data // Total // AbsoluteTiming, 
  RustValue /@ data // Total // AbsoluteTiming}
 ]

(* Out: {{19.3707, 100129.}, {32.3437, 100129.}, {5.59327, 100129.}} *)
```

If you want to measure only the calculation on compiled code without including the time needed for converting the input:

```
Block[{a = NumericArray[Flatten@#, "Real64"] & /@ lis, 
   b = NumericArray[Length /@ #, "Integer64"] & /@ lis},
  MapThread[compiledValue, {a, b}] // Total // AbsoluteTiming
  ] // AbsoluteTiming

(* Out: {5.96117, {0.416077, 100129.}} *)
```

The first timing (`5.96`) is for the whole operation, the second (`0.41`) is for the compiled code, and `100129.` exist to show it returns the same result as shown before.

##### How did we handle ragged arrays

As you might have seen, our compiled function has two arguments, first the flattened data and second the length of each list. In Rust, we partitioned the data like [`TakeList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html).

Note that I still have so many things to learn and I'm sure the code above can be further improved.

Comment: Is my c++ more efficient than your rust?

Comment: @yode Yes, mine took 5.6 seconds which I could reduce to 4.8 but yours is 4.3 seconds on my computer. I guess I should start learning Chinese ;)

Answer (score 3):

Add a method from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271234/how-to-call-the-c-by-the-new-libraryfunctiondeclaration):

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib=CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<numeric>
#include \"WolframCompileLibrary.h\"

using namespace std;

struct ManagedArray{
    MTensor* data;
    mint refcount;
};

struct FixedArray{
    ManagedArray data;
    mint refcount;
};

struct RaggedList{
    FixedArray* data;
    mint refcount;
};

mreal value(vector<vector<mreal>> pix_values) {
    vector<mreal> flatten_pix_values;
    for (auto const& group : pix_values) {
        flatten_pix_values.insert(flatten_pix_values.end(), group.begin(), group.end());
    }

    mreal mean_value = std::accumulate(begin(flatten_pix_values), end(flatten_pix_values), 0.0) / flatten_pix_values.size();

    mreal SST = 0.0;
    for_each(begin(flatten_pix_values), end(flatten_pix_values), [&SST, mean_value](const mreal d) {SST += pow(d - mean_value, 2); });

    mreal SSA = 0;
    for (auto const& group : pix_values) {
        SSA += group.size() * pow(std::accumulate(begin(group), end(group), 0.0) / group.size() - mean_value, 2);
    }
    mreal SSE = SST - SSA;
    int a = pix_values.size() - 1, b = flatten_pix_values.size() - pix_values.size();

    return mreal((SSA / a) / (SSE / b));
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT mreal ragged_value(RaggedList inlis) {
    vector<vector<mreal>> vecs;
    
    for (mint i = 0; i < inlis.data->data.refcount; i++) {
        MTensor tensor = inlis.data->data.data[i];
        auto ptensor = (mreal*)tensor->data;
        vector<mreal> vec(ptensor, ptensor + tensor->nelems);
        vecs.push_back(vec);
    }

    return value(vecs);
}","Ragged_Value",Language->"C++"];
dec=LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun->"ragged_value",lib,{"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64",1]]}->"Real64"];
fcvalue=FunctionCompile[dec,Function[{Typed[lis,"ListVector"::["PackedArray"::["Real64",1]]]},fun[lis]]]
```

### Performance

```
lis = DeleteCases[
   Table[ResourceFunction["RandomSplit"][RandomReal[255, 1000], 10], 
    100000], {}, {2}];
RepeatedTiming[value /@ lis;]
RepeatedTiming[fcvalue /@ lis;]
```

> {11.0433, Null}

> {2.42399, Null}