# How to get a MTensor variable by a vector object

Tags: librarylink, c++, function-compile

*librarylink* have a dirty signature such as:

```
EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int fun(WolframLibraryData libData,mint Argc, MArgument* Args, MArgument Res)
```

But when we are in version *13.1*, we don't have to define this form to call c++ functions as my [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/271362/21532), such as the `sort_add2_fc` or `ragged_mean` in it. But the function must return the specified format, such as `MTensor`,`mint` or `mreal`.

Obviously we can't return a **vector** object. So, if we get a vector in c++, how do I convert it into an **MTensor** object for return? For example, the following $\color{red}{\text{semi-finished}}$ function:

```
#include<vector>
#include "WolframCompileLibrary.h"

using namespace std;

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT MTensor whichVec(mint index) {
    vector<vector<mint>> vecVec = { {7,11,2},{9,6,3,5} };
    vector<mint> result = vecVec[index];
    MTensor res;// How to initialize res with the result

    //current try:
    st_WolframLibraryData libData;
    mint dims[] = { result.size()};
    libData.MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, dims, &res);
    auto p = libData.MTensor_getIntegerData(res);
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), p);

    return res;
}
```

But I don't know what is currently wrong in my code. If this function compiles successfully, then the following functions `fc` should work properly in *MMA*:

```
dec=LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun->"whichVec","dir/*.dll",{"MachineInteger"}-> 
    "PackedArray"::["MachineInteger", 1]];
fc=FunctionCompile[dec,Function[{Typed[lis,"MachineInteger"]}, fun[lis]]]
```

Comment: I meant to say this already on your last question, but please keep in mind that using `std::vector` might not be the best idea if you care about performance. Since `std::vector` always handles its own data, you have to resort to a lot of copying of data into and out of the vector (as you can see from your code), which is potentially quite slow. You might want to consider using some other, non-owning wrapper, such as [`std::ranges::subrange`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/subrange).

Comment: @LukasLang Yes, you are right. I know some data structures that are faster than `std::vector`, like `std::array`, but if I can initialize a `MTensor` with `std::vector`, then I can do it with `std::array`. That's why I'm asking this question

Comment: Well, `std::array` is not really a faster alternative to `std::vector`. It is still owning, the data are just contained within the object rather than on the heap. So unless you're doing some questionable casting, I'm not sure you'll gain anything from using `std::array` over `std::vector`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I introduce a library `WolframRTL_Kernel.lib` then solve this problem:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib=CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include<vector>
#include \"WolframRTL.h\"

using namespace std;
WolframLibraryData libData = WolframLibraryData_new(WolframLibraryVersion); 

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT MTensor whichVec(mint index) {


    vector<vector<mint>> vecVec = { {7,11,2},{9,6,3,5} };
    vector<mint> result = vecVec[index];
    MTensor res;
    mint dims[] = { result.size() };
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, dims, &res);
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), (mint*)res->data);

    WolframLibraryData_free(libData);

    return res;
}","whichVecFile","Language"->"C++","Libraries"->"WolframRTL_Kernel.lib"];

dec=LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun->"whichVec",lib,{"MachineInteger"}->"PackedArray"::["MachineInteger",1]];
fc=FunctionCompile[dec,Function[{Typed[lis,"MachineInteger"]},fun[lis]]]
```

We can use it now:

```
fc[1]
```

> `{9, 6, 3, 5}`

Of course, we can use this code in `c++` code:

```
#pragma comment(lib,"C:/Program Files/Wolfram Research/Mathematica/13.1/SystemFiles/Libraries/Windows-x86-64/WolframRTL_Kernel.lib")
```

---

As the example [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/CCodeGenerator/tutorial/Examples.html#333777088), maybe we need `"Libraries" -> "WolframRTL_Static_Minimal"`, then we get a more large `.dll` file.

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way that works, although I am not sure it is the intended way:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
lib = CCompilerDriver`CreateLibrary["
#include<vector>
#include \"WolframCompileLibrary.h\"

using namespace std;

WolframLibraryData libData;

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int WolframLibrary_initialize( WolframLibraryData \
libData_) {
    libData = libData_;
    return 0;
}

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT MTensor whichVec(mint index) {
    vector<vector<mint>> vecVec = { {7,11,2},{9,6,3,5} };
    vector<mint> result = vecVec[index];
    MTensor res;
    mint dims[] = {result.size()};
    libData->MTensor_new(MType_Integer, 1, dims, &res);
    auto p = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(res);
    copy(result.begin(), result.end(), p);

    return res;
}", "whichVecFile", Language -> "C++"];

LibraryLoad@lib;

dec = LibraryFunctionDeclaration[fun -> "whichVec", 
   lib, {"MachineInteger"} -> "PackedArray"::["MachineInteger", 1]];
fc = FunctionCompile[dec, 
  Function[{Typed[lis, "MachineInteger"]}, fun[lis]]]
(* CompiledCodeFunction[...] *)

fc[0]
(* {7, 11, 2} *)
```

The key difference to your attempt is how the `WolframLibraryData` struct is obtained: You are trying to simply construct one, but this won't work - it needs to be initialized and given to you by the kernel. The best way I found to obtain a pointer to the correct instance is to use `WolframLibrary_initialize` to store the pointer passed into that function. For some reason, the "loading" done by `LibraryFunctionDeclaration`/`FunctionCompile` does not call that initialization routine, so we manually have to call `LibraryLoad` before. As you can see from the code above, this then works as expected.

Comment: Very interesting thought, you got a `WolframLibraryData` by `LibraryLoad`, which I didn't expect at all. If indeed no user can build this structure by code indeed, then I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot man. This problem has been bothering me for many days :)

Comment: I made it in the following answer.